# How should I manage a secure, personal ssh key?

Tags: keyrings, ssh

I need to have a personal ssh key such that:

- I can back up a single file containing my private key, and restore it when I do a new install.
- The private key is never stored in unencrypted form anywhere, including in the file that I back up and restore, but with the necessary exception of my RAM while I am using it.
- Someone with physical access to my machine cannot necessarily use my private key. I should be required to enter a password before it will work, preferably the password to my user account.
- It is not necessary to back up the public key. I should be able to generate that from the private key (but may need sufficient information to decrypt it).

I know that there are a lot of resources explaining how to use ssh key management tools. However, I find them quite complex, and I have proven unable to save my private key when doing new installs in the past. So I would much rather hear some best practices from someone with experience doing exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 9):

Going through your points:

- When you generate a SSH key, it's stored in `~/.ssh/` as `id_rsa` (or `id_dsa`). You can move this from machine to machine as you wish.
- You can ensure its encryption by encrypting `/home/`. There are several sets of instructions on how to do this around the internet but (having never done this myself) I can't honestly suggest one over another. [The one on UbuntuForums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1449168) seems as good as any other. Doing this on a fresh install is easier (you can do it in the installer) but it's not required.
- When you generate your keypair, make sure you set a passphrase. This means that even if somebody gets your private key, they still need that token to use it.
- `ssh-keygen -e` will generate your public key hash from your private key. Do yes, you don't need to back that up (although it wouldn't be hard to do either - it's stored as `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`).

Comment: Doesn't setting a passphrase count as encrypting the key?

Comment: @Vincent Sort of, sure. I'm not sure how paranoid you're trying to be here. If you want to minimise the chance of somebody else getting hold of the key, stick it within an encrypted partition. If you're happy with people being able to get it (if they gain physical access), but can't use it without a passphrase, you can skip that step.